# Navigation bar in appended view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I currently have three view controllers appended to one single view controller called V1. V1 has a horizontal scrollview which can push the other three views on the screen when scrolled.

I would like to embed a Navigation Bar in each of the three view controllers so that each one can have its own independent bar buttons and titles based on which page is scrolled to.

My problem is determining where I embed the navigation bar. I tried V1 but it is not giving the results I would like. How can I make each view have its own navigation bar?

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Changes Navi bar
        // navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 237/255, green: 15/255, blue: 140/255, alpha: 1)
        // navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let v1 = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("A") as! Offers
        let v2 : View2 = View2(nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)        
        let v3 = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("C") as! DiscoveryPage

        self.addChildViewController(v1)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(v1.view)
        v1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        self.addChildViewController(v2)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(v2.view)
        v2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        self.addChildViewController(v3)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(v3.view)
        v3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        //Set the frame

        var v2Frame : CGRect = v2.view.frame
        v2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
        v2.view.frame = v2Frame

        var v3Frame : CGRect = v3.view.frame
        v3Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width * 2
        v3.view.frame = v3Frame

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 3, self.view.frame.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little explanation here, hope it'll answer your question.

If you're using a `UINavigationController` to manage your flow of view controllers. Then you don't need to provide custom navigation bar for every view controller, the top left and right bar button item and title of the view controller are part of [`UINavigationItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html) and `UINavigationItem` is a property of `UIViewController`.

Every time you push a view controller onto a `UINavigationController`, the navigation controller takes the navigation item from view controller and setup its item onto the navigation bar. The navigation bar is managed by `UINavigationController` automatically.

You just need to edit and provide your navigation related info in the associated `UINavigationItem`.

In the storyboard, if you don't see a navigation item associated to a view controller, you can drag an item from objects and drop it inside view controller:

[image: Screenshot]

If you click on a navigation item, you can edit these three option from property inspector:

[image: navigation item property]

If you drag a `UIBarButtonItem` from objects to your `UINavigationItem` associated to your `UIViewController`, it'll automatically add it to your left bar button.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In my scenario which view controller would I be using to embed the Navigation Controller?

Comment: You already have a navigation controller, make it the initial view controller from property inspector. Right now the V1 is your initial view controller, means, when your app loads, it displays v1 as initial view.

Comment: Ive done everything you have said and updated the picture above to illustrate what my storyboard looks like. Can you please explain why the navigation bar is not changing as I horizontally scroll through the scrollview of V1.

Comment: So basically, you've another `UIScrollView` to host more `UIViewController` in `V1`?

Comment: Yes I have used a scrollview to host three other view controllers.

Comment: I added the code where I appended the view controllers. One is a Xib file.

Comment: Okay, in that case, set navigation item to every child view controller. and then listen for scrolling of scroll view, lets say, you came to know that you're showing 2nd child view at that scroll position, get the navigation item of that view controller and set it to v1's navigation item like this: `self.navigationItem = currentlyShowingVC.navigationItem;`

Comment: Thanks i understand what I am supposed to do but I am kinda lost on how to execute that in code. Can you please point me in the right direction to program that in swift. Im sorry i am new to programming.

Comment: What I understand from your question, you're trying to implement a `UIPageViewController` like behavior. like going back and forth with a series of View Controllers, If you look at this tutorial, you would know that your requirements can be filled with usage of [`UIPageViewController`](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you. Ill look into it